# "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:" How To fixed This?

Tags: kotlin

Cannot sync the gradle as following error is appearing.

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
e [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5h4i.png)

Comment: Can you please the gradle file code

Comment: You might want to add your code in the `build.gradle` files in to to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perform good in me:

- Setting\Project Structure\ Gradle Plugin: 7.3.0 and Gradle Version: 7.4.2
- Modules : SDK (33.0) and Build Tool Ver (33.0)
- Step 2: Gradle Script paste this code in **build.gradle**
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piMrD.png)
  `buildscript{
  repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
  }
  }

  allprojects {
  repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  }
  }
  `
- Step 3: Delete dependencyResolutionManagement in **settings.gradle**

Answer (score 0):

My Observations:

1. The problem is with the proxy set with current project.
2. The plugin is not able to get synced with the current project.

What I did to fix the problem:

1. Created a new project
2. Copied the project files.
3. Pasted them into my new project.
4. Problem solved for me